# Display product tabs on product category pages in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product tabs on category page in WooCommerce. I have tried the following code but didn't get any proper solution.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );
```

Comment: what tab you need to display

Comment: @NavnitMishra I want to display product description, Review tab

Comment: do you know it's part of single product page ......

Comment: Yes I have added the that code in page or content .php but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use action hook "woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item" for this purpose.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20);
```

This outputs the product tabs but formatting is a mess. You will need to add custom css to make those tabs function as desired.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added in content-product.php but problem in look and feel of product tab. so how to call that css on this  page. I have used the CDN for css.

Comment: You will need to use this action hook in your theme's function.php file. And regarding the custom css, that you will need to add into your themes css file or create new css file and enqueue it.

Comment: added in functions.php but css of tabs not loading

Comment: css for the tabs will not load automatically. Since this is customization, you will have to create custom css for those tabs. You will either have to write new css rules (with reference to your page structure) in your theme's css file or you will need to altogether create new css file and enqueue that new css file in your theme.

Comment: I tried for custom css for this page but not affecting any on this page.

Comment: I got that look & feel but all tabs are shown. how to hide that tabs so please help asap.

Comment: Which tabs are shown and which of those you want to hide?

Comment: sorry I want hide tab content not whole tab. All tab contents are displayed with one by one. so how to hide that tab content for non active tab.

Comment: Check the css classes assigned to the tabs and set them as 'display:none' in your css file.

Comment: that tab contains inline css.

Comment: I have tried this solution using jquery but not working jQuery("#tabid").click(function{ jQuery(this).css("display","block"); });

Comment: can you post a link which we can see?

Comment: I am trying on local

Comment: please suggest any solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
    just create or overwrite your category page.php file with


    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <?php
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                 */
                do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
            ?>
    <?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt ) ?>
        <a class="more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More >></a>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' ); ?>

    after this 


    global $post;

    if ( ! $post->post_excerpt ) return;
    ?>
    <div itemprop="description">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

 try this hope it's helpfull to you..

and the second method to add description on your category page simple copy code and past in your function.php file 

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'my_add_cat_description', 12);

function my_add_cat_description ($category) {
$cat_id=$category->term_id;
$prod_term=get_term($cat_id,'product_cat');
$description=$prod_term->description;
echo '<div class="shop_cat_desc">'.$description.'</div>';
}
```

Comment: But I want to display the custom tabs also..?

Answer (score 0):

corrected solutions

```css
 .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs{
list-style:none;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
margin:0 ;/*0 1.618em*/
padding:0;
}

 .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li {
background: #EFEFEF;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
margin:0;
}

 .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active{
    border-color:#78c8ce;
}
.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a {
display:inline-block;
font-weight:600;
color:#606060;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:12px;
padding:10px 20px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
color:#7a7a7a;
}
.noreviews a{color:#78c8ce;}
 .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active {
background-color:#78c8ce;
z-index:2;color:#FFF;
border-bottom-color:#78c8ce;
border-top-left-radius: 2px;
border-top-right-radius: 2px;

}

.woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs li.active a{
color:inherit;
text-shadow:inherit;
}

#rating_chzn{display: none;}
 .woocommerce-tabs ul.tabs:before{
position:absolute;
content:" ";
width:100%;
bottom:0;
left:0;
border-bottom:1px solid #EFEFEF;
z-index:1;
}

 .woocommerce-tabs .panel {
margin:0 0 2em;
padding:15px 0;
}

 .woocommerce-tabs .accordion-group.panel{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 20);
```